# Why does my ceiling fan turn itself on at night?

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

We have a ceiling fan with three lights that came with the house, and that is operated by an electronic switch driven by a 9V battery and with 5 buttons: Hi, Med, Lo, Off (for the fan) and Light (a toggle for the lights). At around 11ish pm every night, the fan turns itself on. This great in summer, but is quite annoying in winter. I suspect this is a remote controlled fan of sorts, but I have no remote control for it that I can find.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can stop it?

Comment: sounds like it may be programmable. Check owner's manual online to see if it can be reprogrammed.

Comment: maybe a neighbors garage door opener?

Comment: The switch is a remote. Find the manual, and change the codes on it - it may be done by some key sequence, or there may be jumpers on the remote and inside the fan that have to match. It seems a bit unlikely that it's interference or a signal from something your neighbours have if it happens consistently every night and at no other time of day, but it's worth a shot to start with.

Comment: Hey @gregmac: It sounds like you are suggesting I open up the switch panel and change codes on what is likely an independent battery-operated wireless electronic switch for the fan?

Comment: If you can supply a photo or a model number, we might be able to help more.  An X10 device, which is possible in this format, would have a certain set of solutions.  Also is it exactly 11pm, or approximately 11pm?

Answer (score 3):

If you live in an apartment, then the chance of your neighbor having the same fan is pretty high. Try setting the dip switches on the fan receiver and remote to a new setting. Just make sure they're the same.

Answer (score 1):

My Hunter remote control turns on the light fairly often in the middle of the night.  I am convinced it is because of power spikes or momentary interruptions.  How do I know?

I can trip the breaker that feeds this fan and then  flip it back on and the light comes on almost every time.

It is on the same circuit as the garage door opener but the door opener has no problems.

Perhaps a surge protector could be installed to help but I have not pursued this.

Comment: Flipping the switch/breaker quickly is a feature of the fan. If you install a fan in place of an existing ceiling light but then misplace the remote, you can turn on the light by turning off the switch then back on again.